# Why is my Go program so slow when navigating the files

Tags: go

Why is this program so slow? I thought the code was fairly optimized, but it takes significantly long than the find command when use on my root filesystem.

It takes about 4 minutes, as opposed to the find command which takes about 40 seconds.

I tried removing the sorting algorithm, but doesn't speed up the program.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "io/fs"
    "log"
    "os"
    "sort"
    "sync"

    "github.com/google/fscrypt/filesystem"
    "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
    "gopkg.in/alecthomas/kingpin.v2"
)

var (
    mountpoint = kingpin.Flag("mount", "The mount to find the largest file usages. Can be a subath of mount").Required().String()
    limit      = kingpin.Flag("limit", "The maximum number of files return to the display").Default("10").Short('l').Int()
)
var device string

type fileDisplay struct {
    Size int64
    Path string
}
type bySize []fileDisplay

func (a bySize) Len() int           { return len(a) }
func (a bySize) Less(i, j int) bool { return a[i].Size < a[j].Size }
func (a bySize) Swap(i, j int)      { a[i], a[j] = a[j], a[i] }

var fileChan = make(chan fileDisplay)
var files []fileDisplay

func main() {
    log.SetOutput(io.Discard)
    kingpin.Version("0.0.1")
    kingpin.Parse()
    //Define limit after parsing
    logrus.SetLevel(logrus.FatalLevel)
    if (*mountpoint)[len(*mountpoint)-1:] != "/" {
        *mountpoint = *mountpoint + "/"
    }
    fmt.Println("Finding the top", *limit, "largest files on filesystem", *mountpoint, "\n================================================")
    mount, err := filesystem.FindMount(*mountpoint)
    if err != nil {
        logrus.Fatal(err)
    }
    device = mount.Device

    entries, err := os.ReadDir(*mountpoint)
    if err != nil {
        logrus.Fatal(err)
    }
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    getFiles(*mountpoint, entries, &wg)
    go func() {
        defer close(fileChan)
        wg.Wait()
    }()
    var last int64
    for file := range fileChan {
        if file.Size > last {
            files = append(files, file)
        } else {
            files = append([]fileDisplay{file}, files...)
        }
    }
    sort.Sort(bySize(files))
    var shortFiles []fileDisplay
    if len(files) > *limit {
        shortFiles = files[len(files)-*limit:]
    } else {
        shortFiles = files
    }

    for _, file := range shortFiles {
        fmt.Println(file.Path, file.DisplaySizeIEC())
    }

}

func getFiles(start string, entries []fs.DirEntry, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    for _, entry := range entries {
        wg.Add(1)
        go handleEntry(start, entry, wg)
    }

}

func handleEntry(start string, entry fs.DirEntry, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    var file fileDisplay
    mount, err := filesystem.FindMount(start + entry.Name())
    if err != nil {
        logrus.Fatalln(err, start+entry.Name())
        return
    }
    if mount.Device == device {
        if entry.Type().IsRegular() {
            fileInfo, err := os.Stat(start + entry.Name())
            if err != nil {
                logrus.Fatalln(err, start+entry.Name())
                return
            }
            file.Path = start + entry.Name()
            file.Size = fileInfo.Size()
            fileChan <- file
        } else if entry.IsDir() {
            entries, err := os.ReadDir(start + entry.Name())
            if err != nil {
                logrus.Fatalln(err, start+entry.Name())
                return
            }
            logrus.Info("Searching ", start+entry.Name())
            getFiles(start+entry.Name()+"/", entries, wg)
        }
    }

}

func (f *fileDisplay) DisplaySizeIEC() string {
    const unit = 1024
    b := f.Size
    if b < unit {
        return fmt.Sprintf("%dB", b)
    }
    div, exp := int64(unit), 0
    for n := b / unit; n >= unit; n /= unit {
        div *= unit
        exp++
    }
    return fmt.Sprintf("%.2f%ciB",
        float64(b)/float64(div), "KMGTPE"[exp])
}
```

Edit: I tried removing the channel and just appending to the slice. This sped it up, but it's not safe because multiple routines could be accessing it.

Comment: One possible issue is that the program does not buffer output.  Try this: Add `bw := bufio.NewWriter(os.Stdout)` before the output loop.  Print to the buffered writer: `fmt.Fprintln(bw, file.Path, file.DisplaySizeIEC())`.  Flush the writer after the loop `bw.Flush()`.

Comment: @CeriseLimón Thanks. That wasn't the issue. It seems to be choking when ranging over the channel. I believe a single range over the channel is too slow

Comment: How does the performance compare if you do it serially (no goroutines)?

Comment: @Ry- It's pretty much the same.

Comment: 1 question: Can you get specific timing per function/high level component of your program so that it can be identified where the time goes (you can also use the go profiler).
2 1 hint: If these are many go routines, the defer style is slow: Defer runs when the go runtime thinks it is time to run this, this can lead to high cumulative waits on the actual return f the function since the function will not return until the defer has been executed. While it might be less pretty, a few just `wg.Done()` statements instead of defer, can make a large difference.

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen I don't have the timings any more, but I did find that the ranging over the channel was causing the slowness.  Routines were staying open until the range got to their element. It also caused a big memory problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My final draft involved dropping the channel and using `sync.RWMutex` to lock the list and a custom append function to append with the lock. This allowed me to drop the channel and use append without risking multiple routines editing the same slice.

I dropped the channel because this was causing routines to stay open until the for loop over the open channel could reach their message. My channek operations were [blocking](https://gobyexample.com/non-blocking-channel-operations). So the routines caused it to slow to the speed of the for loop iterating over the channel.

You can see the differences here:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "io/fs"
    "log"
    "os"
    "sort"
    "sync"

    "github.com/google/fscrypt/filesystem"
    "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
    "gopkg.in/alecthomas/kingpin.v2"
)

var (
    mountpoint = kingpin.Flag("mount", "The mount to find the largest file usages. Can be a subath of mount").Required().String()
    limit      = kingpin.Flag("limit", "The maximum number of files return to the display").Default("10").Short('l').Int()
)
var device string

type fileDisplays struct {
    sync.RWMutex
    Files []fileDisplay
}

var files fileDisplays

type fileDisplay struct {
    Size int64
    Path string
}
type bySize []fileDisplay

func (a bySize) Len() int           { return len(a) }
func (a bySize) Less(i, j int) bool { return a[i].Size < a[j].Size }
func (a bySize) Swap(i, j int)      { a[i], a[j] = a[j], a[i] }

func main() {
    log.SetOutput(io.Discard)
    kingpin.Version("0.0.1")
    kingpin.Parse()
    //Define limit after parsing
    logrus.SetLevel(logrus.FatalLevel)
    if (*mountpoint)[len(*mountpoint)-1:] != "/" {
        *mountpoint = *mountpoint + "/"
    }
    fmt.Println("Finding the top", *limit, "largest files on filesystem", *mountpoint, "\n================================================")
    mount, err := filesystem.FindMount(*mountpoint)
    if err != nil {
        logrus.Fatal(err)
    }
    device = mount.Device

    entries, err := os.ReadDir(*mountpoint)
    if err != nil {
        logrus.Fatal(err)
    }
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    getFiles(*mountpoint, entries, &wg)
    wg.Wait()
    sort.Sort(bySize(files.Files))
    var shortFiles []fileDisplay
    if len(files.Files) > *limit {
        shortFiles = files.Files[len(files.Files)-*limit:]
    } else {
        shortFiles = files.Files
    }

    for _, file := range shortFiles {
        fmt.Println(file.Path, file.DisplaySizeIEC())
    }

}

func getFiles(start string, entries []fs.DirEntry, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    for _, entry := range entries {
        wg.Add(1)
        go handleEntry(start, entry, wg)
    }

}

func handleEntry(start string, entry fs.DirEntry, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    var file fileDisplay
    mount, err := filesystem.FindMount(start + entry.Name())
    if err != nil {
        logrus.Errorln(err, start+entry.Name())
        return
    }
    if mount.Device == device {
        if entry.Type().IsRegular() {
            fileInfo, err := os.Stat(start + entry.Name())
            if err != nil {
                logrus.Errorln(err, start+entry.Name())
                return
            }
            file.Path = start + entry.Name()
            file.Size = fileInfo.Size()
            files.Append(file)
        } else if entry.IsDir() {
            entries, err := os.ReadDir(start + entry.Name())
            if err != nil {
                logrus.Errorln(err, start+entry.Name())
                return
            }
            logrus.Info("Searching ", start+entry.Name())
            getFiles(start+entry.Name()+"/", entries, wg)
        }
    }

}

func (f *fileDisplay) DisplaySizeIEC() string {
    const unit = 1024
    b := f.Size
    if b < unit {
        return fmt.Sprintf("%dB", b)
    }
    div, exp := int64(unit), 0
    for n := b / unit; n >= unit; n /= unit {
        div *= unit
        exp++
    }
    return fmt.Sprintf("%.2f%ciB",
        float64(b)/float64(div), "KMGTPE"[exp])
}

func (fd *fileDisplays) Append(item fileDisplay) {
    fd.Lock()
    defer fd.Unlock()

    fd.Files = append(fd.Files, item)
}
```